# How to get in keycloak a specific value from the openid connect (user info)?

Tags: openid-connect, mapper, keycloak, userinfo

I'm trying to get the groups to which a user belongs, using the post man to make a request to http://mykeycloak/auth/realms/RealmX/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
with the Authorization header. If a do a get request I receve the json with sub, name and preferred_username this is ok. But when doing a post I get the error code 403. I just want to get the email.

POST /auth/realms/RealmX/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: mykeycloak
Authorization: Bearer "atoken"
claims: {"userinfo":{"email":null}}

What am I doing wrong?[Already set up a mapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZCHA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak and OpenID Connect are REST APIs, which means GET is used to fetch information, while PUT and POST are used to create and edit records.

In other words, doing a POST on userinfo implies you are attempting to update/edit the user's information. Reason for the 403 error is that POST is not allowed (i.e. no editing) via the userinfo endpoint.